# Django py manage.py makemigrate

Tags: python, django, makemigrations

What can I make with it? I'm beginner in python and django. I download it and I i wrote py manage.py makemigrate and I've get error. Can u help me?

[image]

Comment: What is databse part of your setting.py? Share it!

Comment: You don't have DB_NAME environment variable, that you probably use while settings your database connection.

Comment: Can you say the steps in order since startapp till makemigrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with your DB configuration in the `setting.py`. If you are using the default SQLite then copy/paste this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

and your project will work just fine. After this, run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate #copy all migrations to the database
python manage.py createsuperuser #to have a admin user to login to adminpanel
python manage.py runserver #starting the server
```

Otherwise, take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/) how to connect MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle databases and required configurations.

Your error is in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ12f.jpg):

SQLite is not like MySQL or other databases. Actually, it is not a real database. You are using a port, username, password and etc. These are the cause of the error. SQLite is not running in the server or another place. It is just a single file contains data information. Update yours to mine above and it should start work again or change your database to MySQL or others.

Comment: what if i get next error? ;D "raise KeyError(key) from None   KeyError: 'DB_USER' "

Comment: can you share your settings.py? Because when you create a new project this errors should not be raised if you havent touch the database configurations

Comment: I would suggest you to delete all migrations and database and re run makemigrations and migrate

Comment: https://imgur.com/mriZJ1v  https://imgur.com/umgDTWj  https://imgur.com/AluPbx4  https://imgur.com/ggVYSb8

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply all environment variables that are listed in your settings file. Such as `DB_NAME` that presented in your screenshot. Search for `os.environ[<VARIABLE_NAME>]`, every `VARIABLE_NAME` should be defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner it is better to stay with the documentation and do like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

If you could share the DB part of the settings.py it would help.

Generally `python manage.py startapp appname` should create the necessary files for you.
After which a `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` should work properly. And this should not come.

Comment: This is not a answer to the question, just a suggestion and doesn't mention any new approach.

Comment: Well, the OP said they typed `python manage.py makemigrate` which isn't the correct command; this answer provides the correctly spelled command. Beyond that, it is solid advice for a beginner.